# how to make function return more than one value

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var Evalcard =  function(number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        this.name = "Ace";
        this.value = 11;
    }
    else if (number == 11) {
        this.name = "Jack";
        this.value = 10;
    }
    else if (number == 12) {
        this.name = "Queen";
        this.value = 10;
    }
    else if (number == 13) {
        this.name = "King";
        this.value = 10;
    }

    return {this.name,this.value};
```

I'm pretty sure this `return` statement is not correct. How do you make a function return more than one value? Any help at all would be great.

Comment: All these answer below are good, but don't use `this` in your situation. You will need to declare two variables: `var name, value;` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you probably want to return either an array or an object literal:

```
return { name: this.name, value: this.value };
// later: EvalCard(...).name; EvalCard(...).number;


return [ this.name, this.value ];
// later: EvalCard(...)[0]; EvalCard(...)[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
return [this.name, this.value];
```

Comment: @Oliver_Weiler--If I return it as an array, how do I call the values without an array name?

Comment: @codeninja - `Evalcard(1)[0]` and `Evalcard(1)[1]` where the values within the brackets reference the corresponding key of the value within the array.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass an object literal as you came so close to doing:

```
return { name:this.name, value:this.value };
```

or you could pass an array:

```
return [this.name, this.value];
```

Of course if your code is executed in the global context, you'll be setting `name` and `value` on the `window` object. If you're using `Evalcard` as a constructor, you wont *need* a return statement, the object being created will automatically be set:

```
var e = new Evalcard(1);
console.log(e.name); //outputs "Ace" if you remove the return statement.
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CxTWt/

```
var Evalcard = function(number) {
    var evalName, evalValue;    
    if (number == 1) {         
        evalName= "Ace";         
        evalValue = 11;     
    }else if (number == 11) {         
        evalName = "Jack";         
        evalValue = 10;     
    }else if (number == 12) {         
        evalName= "Queen";         
        evalValue= 10;     
    }else if (number == 13) {         
        evalName= "King";         
        evalValue = 10;     
    }      
    return {name: evalName, value: evalValue};
}

alert(Evalcard(1).name+" "+Evalcard(1).value);
```

Comment: Would it not depend on the handling of the returned values?  I agree that you can simply return the result as an object, but that doesn't mean its the only way.  I think without knowing the full context then it could go either way.

Comment: Yes, it is not the only way. I agree with your last edit now.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
return [this.name, this.value];
```

Comment: @Gabriel_Ross--If I return it as an array, how do I call the values without an array name?

Comment: (name, value) = Evalcard(number);

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
function xyz() {
...
var x = 1;
var y = 'A';
return [x, y];
}
var a = xyz();
document.write('x=' + a[0] + ' and y = ' + a[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to return an array or give keys to the object you are returning

So

```
return [this.name,this.value];
```

Or

```
return {name:this.name,value:this.value};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would return an object:

```
return {key1:value1, key2:value2}
```

Then you can reference it like so:

```
myReturn.key1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return it in a number of different ways:

Array

```
return [this.name,this.value];
```

Object

```
return {first:this.name, second:this.value};
```

String

```
return this.name+":"+this.value;
```